# Getting Angular to Recognize My Active Tab Without Refreshing Page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am applying a lighter background and an underline for active tabs in my Angular 2 app. However, at present, the active tab styling ONLY applies when I refresh the page. When I first hover over an item, the styling is applied, and then when I click through to that tab (i.e. making it active) the styling disappears, and will only show up if I refresh the page. So clearly this is not the desired behavior. Somehow Angular is not checking for styling changes until after page refresh, instead of on the event.

This is what my view looks like:

```
<div class="page-content-header">
    <div class="page-content-header-item" [class.selected]="isSection('section1')" routerLink="/section1" routerLinkActive="selected">Section 1</div>
    <div class="page-content-header-item" [class.selected]="isSection('section2')" routerLink="/section2" routerLinkActive="selected">Section 2</div>
    <div class="page-content-header-item" [class.selected]="isSection('section3')" routerLink="/section3" routerLinkActive="selected">Section 3</div>
</div>
```

And here's the relevant css:

```
.app-page-view .page-content-header-item:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.app-page-view .page-content-header-item.selected {
  border-bottom: solid 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
```

The component looks like this:

```
// Imports above here removed for brevity

    @Component({
      selector: 'section-tabs',
      templateUrl: './section-tabs.html',
    })
    export class SectionTabsComponent implements OnInit {

        private section;
        documents = [];
        errorMsg: string;

        constructor(private countsService: countsService) {}

        ngOnInit() {
          this.countsService.getCount('info')
              .subscribe(resRecordsData => this.documents = resRecordsData,
              responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
        }

        /**
         * Returns true if the specified name matches the current section
         * @param name
         */
        public isSection(name:string): boolean {
            return this.section && name === this.section;
        }

    }
```

What do I need to change to have Angular recognize when I have landed on an active tab, without having to refresh the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need  to manually set\unset class, just use `routerLinkActive`

```
<a class="page-content-header-item" routerLink="/section1" routerLinkActive="selected">Section 1</a>
```

Check this [Plunker!!](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zw1hDM4nWL7lLnkoVihM?p=preview)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: That did it, @Madhu. Thanks!

Comment: @Muirik: Glad it helped, you can accept answer, Cheers!!